# why does my Form application give me a Format Exception was unhandeld warning

Tags: c#, exception

hello I'm new to this site, so I'm sorry if i don't explain correctly:

I'm creating a C# Form app, and my app has no errors, but gives me a FormatException was unhandeld once i clear my input field.

This is the only applicable code to this function:

```
    private void txtR_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        R = Convert.ToInt32(txtR.Text);
        E2 = Convert.ToInt32(txtE2.Text);
        E = R * E2;
        txtE.Text = E.ToString();

        R = Convert.ToInt32(txtR.Text);
        D2 = Convert.ToInt32(txtD2.Text);
        D = R * D2;
        txtD.Text = D.ToString();

        R = Convert.ToInt32(txtR.Text);
        P2 = Convert.ToInt32(txtP2.Text);
        P = R * P2;
        txtP.Text = P.ToString();
     }
```

Comment: forgot 2 say the P,D,R,E,D2,D2,P2,E2; are float values

Answer (score 2):

The function `Convert.ToInt32()` can't handle a zero-length string, so you can't leave `txtR` (or any other text field) empty.

Also, I would recommend that you consider not having this code running in an `onTextChanged` event. A common scenario might be you erasing the content of `txtR`, thus triggering `onTextChanged` and having the exception being thrown.

In any case, to make your code bullet-proof, it is a good idea to use `Int32.TryParse()` to ensure the conversions will work, as sharp12345 suggested.

---

`Convert.ToInt32()` documentation: [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b.aspx). Read the `FormatException` bit.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is giving you an error when you clear the field is because you are trying to convert an empty string into a number. When you clear the field, `txtR` is equal to String.Empty, therefore it cannot be converted into a number. When it is empty:

```
R = Convert.ToInt32(txtR.Text);
```

Is pretty much the same as:

```
R = Convert.ToInt32("");
```

Which it cannot do. To fix this issue you first need to check if all fields have any value:

```
    private void txtR_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(txtR.Text.Trim().Length != 0 
    && txtE2.Text.Trim().Length != 0 
    && txtD2.Text.Trim().Length != 0 
    && txtP2.Text.Trim().Length != 0)
    {

        R = float.Parse(txtR.Text);
        E2 = float.Parse(txtE2.Text);
        E = R * E2;
        txtE.Text = E.ToString();

        R = float.Parse(txtR.Text);
        D2 = float.Parse(txtD2.Text);
        D = R * D2;
        txtD.Text = D.ToString();

        R = float.Parse(txtR.Text);
        P2 = float.Parse(txtP2.Text);
        P = R * P2;
        txtP.Text = P.ToString();

    }
    else{
        MessageBox.Show("One or more of the fields were empty!");
    {
 }
```

Hope this Helps!

Comment: @Steve Oh woops, I really need to get some sleep!

Answer (score 1):

You should be using [`int.TryParse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) to check if the values entered are correct and not empty or a string.

So, this block of code:

```
R = Convert.ToInt32(txtR.Text);
E2 = Convert.ToInt32(txtE2.Text);
E = R * E2;
txtE.Text = E.ToString();
```

should be converted to:

```
if (int.TryParse(txtR.Text, out R) && int.TryParse(txtE2.Text, out E2)) {        
    E = R * E2;
    txtE.Text = E.ToString();
}
```

The same will work for float just like int.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Single.TryParse` when converting an user input string in numeric values (floats in your case, not integers) .
Normally, you could not easily prevent the user to insert some bogus value and your code will fail.
Instead TryParse allow you to test the input string without exception in case of invalid input

```
    // Try to convert the R value just one time, everything fails if this fails
    if(!Single.TryParse(txtR.Text, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out R))
        return; 
    if(Single.TryParse(txtE2.Text, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out E2)) 
    {
        E = R * E2; 
        txtE.Text = E.ToString(); 
    }

    if(Single.TryParse(txtD2.Text, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out D2))
    {
        D = R * D2; 
        txtD.Text = D.ToString(); 
    }

    if(Single.TryParse(txtP2.Text, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out P2))
    {
        P = R * P2; 
        txtP.Text = P.ToString(); 
    }
```

[See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26sxas5t.aspx) on MSDN for a reference